# Read GridMVC select row in javascript button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, grid.mvc

I have GridMVC in project with checkbox. 
 while click button i need to read row which checkbox selected.
 I tried to read all data from GridMVC in button click but not working.

**MY Code**

**GRID**

```
@using GridMvc.Html

@{
    if (Model != null)
    {
        <div class="table-responsive">
            @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
            {
               columns.Add()
               .Encoded(false)
               .Sanitized(false)
               .SetWidth(10)
               .RenderValueAs(o => Html.CheckBox("checked", o.select));
               columns.Add(c => c.product_code).Titled(Resources.Resource.product_id);
               columns.Add(c => c.product_name).Titled(Resources.Resource.product_name);
               columns.Add(c => c.unit).Titled(Resources.Resource.unit);
            }).WithPaging(10).Sortable(true).EmptyText("No data found").Named("GridSearch")
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        <label>No Data Found</label>
    }

}
```

**View**

```
 <div id="newgrid" class="col-sm-12 table-responsive" style="width:100%;height:300px;margin-top:3%;padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;">
    @{Html.Partial("ResultGrid", new List<SCM_MVC.Models.Search>()); }
   </div>
   <div class="form-actions" style="margin-top:2%;padding-left:2%;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="btnok" style="width:100px"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> OK </button>
   </div>
```

**Java Script**

```
 $('#btnok').click(function () {

        var items = $('.grid-mvc').val();
        alert(items);
    })
```

How to read GRIDMVC in javascript.

Comment: Where is the element with class selector `.grid-mvc`? I didn't found it in your code sample. Are you want to post selected row or all rows inside that grid?

Comment: its class name of grid div @TetsuyaYamamoto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find row using **HTML Element**.

**Grid**

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
   {
       columns.Add()
       .Encoded(false)
       .Sanitized(false)
       .SetWidth(10)
       .RenderValueAs(o => new HtmlString
               (
                 "<input id='hiddenValue' type='hidden' class='check' value='" + o.Id + "'/>"+
                 "<input type='checkbox' class='check' value=" +o.select+"/>"
               ));
       columns.Add(c => c.FirstName).Titled("First Name");
       columns.Add(c => c.LastName).Titled("Last Name");
   }).WithPaging(10).Sortable(true).EmptyText("No data found").Named("GridSearch")
```

**View**

```
<div id="newgrid" class="col-sm-12 table-responsive" style="width:100%;height:300px;margin-top:3%;padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;">
    @Html.Partial("ResultGrid", Model)
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#btnok').click(function () {        
    //for find all row
    var items = $(".grid-mvc").find(".grid-table > tbody").children();

    $.each(items, function (i, row) {            
        if ($(row).find('.check').is(':checked')) {
            //get text of firstname column using inner text.
            alert($(row).children()[1].innerText);
            //get text of lastname column using inner text.
            alert($(row).children()[2].innerText);
            //using each loop get data with checked row.
            alert($(row).find('#hiddenValue').val())
        }
    })        
})
```

Comment: Can you explain more? I tested this code. Its work properly for find rows of current page with selected checkbox.

Comment: am trying to get value of "First Name" its not showing to me

Comment: You can get **FirstName** using inner text of **<td>**. Look into my javascript code. I edited code for show alert of FirstName & LastName using inner text.